# Decide which component should be displayed by string name

Tags: angular, angular2-template

If have a few objects of different types. Every object has its own components. For example I have `typeA, typeB, typeC` and for every type its own component `typeAComponent, typeBComponent, typeCComponent`.

Currently I have a big ngSwitch:

```
    <div [ngSwitch]="variant.type">
            <div *ngSwitchCase="'typeA'">
                <typeAComponent></typeAComponent>
            </div>
            <div *ngSwitchCase="'typeB'">
                <typeBComponent></typeBComponent>
            </div>
            <div *ngSwitchCase="'typeC'">
                <typeCComponent></typeCComponent>
            </div>
     </div>
```

Is there any possibility to avoid this switch-case?

`variant.type` contains the type of the component. So maybe it is possible to define the something like `<{{variant.type + 'Component'}}>

Why do I want to do this? In future versions there will be additional types. The idea is that only the `typeXComponent` has to be written and no other code has to be changed. (Currently I have to add a new case to the switch-case.)

In PHP you can instantiate a class by only knowing the classname as a string

```
 $myClassName = 'myClass';
 $instance = new $myClassName();
```

Something similar I need for Angular :D

Does anyone have a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may load component dynamically using ComponentType not string Class. you may create a dictionary which will have class Name and ComponentType in it, which you may use to load component Dynamically.

In the Component where you are loading other components dynamically

```
   //inject the component factory resolver 
   constructor(private componentFactoryResolver:ComponentFactoryResolver){}

   //accept a component and a viewContainerRef (where you want to load the component)
     loadComponent(component:Type, target:ViewContainerRef){          
      let componentFactory =    this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
      target.createComponent(componentFactory);
    }
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I've used a special json data structure to achieve this ;)